# Is there a extension or a way to highlight corretly code in laravel blade directive @section .... @end section in visualstudio code?

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, laravel-blade

In my vs code, code between this directive dont highlight corretly.
I tried search for extension for this case but saddly with no results.
[my case on picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YIiGx.png)

Comment: Have you tried this? https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=onecentlin.laravel-blade

Comment: i have installed this extension, and like you see in pic, highlight is gone :(

Answer (score 0):

You did right by using `@section()` and `@yield()` the output in the main **app.blade.php** file. This is the first option to use extra js and CSS for a particular page.

But you are missing the `<script>` tag if you not doing `@yield('script')` inside the `<script>` tag in your `app.blade.php`.

Second option is use `@push()` instead of `@section()` and use `@stack()` instead of `@yield()`.

**@push** directive push the code to parent **@stack**

Eg.

- app.blade.php

  - @stack('css')
  - @yield('content')
  - @stack('script')
- page.blade.php

  - `@extend('app')`
  - `@section('content')`

    - `@component('child-component')`
    - `@push('script')` push only child component script or css
  - `@endsection
  - `@push('script')` push this page script or css

Comment: I assumed that as well. that why used **if**

Comment: I did not miss <script> tag, this is my code in app.blade.php
```
<script type="text/javascript">
        @yield('javascript')
    </script> ```

Comment: OK, thanks, i will try push and stack, but mayby there is a way to fix it without this?

Comment: Yes, you can use extensions like **Syntax Highlighter**. I personally use the **ATOM theme** in a dark mode which is best as I see. You get highlighted js and CSS

Comment: Can you explain how to handle it with **Syntax Highlighter** ? In **ATOM theme** i have still just grey text inside @directives insted highlingt js code, only if its JS code, html for example highlight normaly. Its really annoying :(

Comment: You have to write your code inside of `<script>` tag to get highlighted view